# Where can I find a proof of the 4 color theorem

Tags: graph-theory, coloring, planar-graphs

Where can I find a reasonably understandable proof on how to reduce to a finite number of configurations?
Also any videos on this would also be appreciated

Comment: Many references here: https://www.google.com/search?q=4+COLOR+THEOREM+PROOF&safe=images&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjk0aSGyorjAhUNz4UKHR-cDO0Q_AUIFSgA&biw=1097&bih=554

Comment: @NoChance   whats a reasonably understandable explanation for how one could reduce to  finitely many cases that you could check with a computer  
Ideally not using weird terminology like simplicial complex, simplicial immersion etc.

Comment: I wish I could provide an answer but I don't know.